# Slice pandas dataframe to get only oneday's data

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select one specific day's data from a Pandas DataFrame.

```
dfx = dfx.set_index('Time')
df9 = dfx.between_time('2013-07-17 00:00','2013-07-17 23:59')
```

`between_time` just check the time period. Is there a similar method that I could use to get data during the period of `2013-07-17 00:00 to 2013-07-17 23:59`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without setting the index it worked fine as following.

```
df9 = df[(df['Time'] > '2013-07-17 00:00') & (df['Time'] < '2013-07-17 23:59')]
```

Comment: if Time is a `DatetimeIndex` you should be able to do the following as well: `df['2013-07-17']`